# Executing Source command in bash for MAC

Tags: macos, bash, bash-scripting

How do I call the source command in a bash script for Mac 
This is my current script

```
echo Launch virtualEnvironment
source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate
```

so basically the source command isn't executed at all when I run this script 
 can someone please let me know what I doing wrong or if this is possible in the first place .Note I am quite new to this and any help would be appreciated

Comment: What happens if you add `#!/bin/bash` as the first line of your script?

Comment: nothing unfortunately